# Aframe Entity disappear after device rotation

Tags: aframe

I created a button to make some entities visible or not by clicking this button. But if I rotate the phone right after clicking the button, the entities become visible for a few seconds and then suddenly disappear. If I keep the position of the phone after the button is pressed, the items are displayed correctly. How to fix this bug?
[Glitch code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/harmonious-spectacular-garnet?path=index.html%3A66%3A12), a short [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14iCp9XLCd54loiN60YfyXM4d0sDBCw00/view?usp=sharing)  with the proof

Comment: If possible, please make the code as small as possible and include it here, for ease of reading and in case your link goes down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity is disappearing (or appearing out of nowhere) because the [cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html) emits two `click` events:

- one from the actual touch
- the second one because of fusing. The cursor waits for `fuseTimeout`ms  (1500 by default) and emits a `click`.

Once you disable fusing, all should work as expected

```
cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: false"
```